# Wie sagt man "To half believe"?

Tags: grammar

Ich habe mir einen StephenKing-Film angeschaut und im Film hat Belch zu seinem Freund gesagt:

> It doesn't matter if they don't believe or half believe at all

Hier ist mein Versuch:

Egal, ob sie entweder glauben, noch  halb glauben.

Comment: Is "at all" part of "doesn't matter at all" or should the sentence read "It doesn't matter if they half believe or don't believe at all"?

Comment: "etwas halb glauben" ist kein Sprachbild, das im Deutschen nicht üblich ist. Auch "to be too clever by half" kann man nicht mit Hälfte oder halb übersetzen.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "teilweise" anstatt halb? "Es ist egal, ob sie es (nur) teilweise oder (gar) nicht glauben." Falls meine Übersetzung korrekt ist schlage ich anstatt "nicht" entweder "gar nicht" oder "überhaupt nicht" vor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Phrase *etwas halb glauben* ist im Deutschen nicht gängig. Für besonders starken Glauben ist aber *fest (an etwas) glauben* üblich. Daher würde ich den Satz umstellen (zuerst den schwachen Glauben, dann den starken Glauben), und würde das wie folgt übersetzen:

> Es ist egal, ob sie einfach nur glauben, oder ob sie wirklich fest glauben.

Ich denke, dass das, was King damit sagen wollte, recht gut rüber kommt, obwohl die Satzstellung nun umgedreht ist.